# What is the groovy << operator mean in this context?

Tags: groovy

In a groovy tutorial, I encountered the following code:

```
class DateTagLib {
  def thisYear = {
    out << Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)
  }
}
```

I don't know what the `<<` means, and I'm having no luck with google.

**Edit:**  I now know that `<<` sometimes is a bit shift.  But what does it mean here?

Comment: Without having seen a line of Groovy in my entire life, it looks like `out << foo` might be syntax for `return foo`. Or out is some kind of object with a funky overload that results in the same thing, i.e. the `<<` operator on the `out` object simply returns it's parameter value...

Comment: seems like a '<<=' would be more appropriate here but i don't really understand it either.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In groovy, the bitwise operators can be overridden with the `leftShift (<<)` and `rightShift (>>)` methods defined on the class.  It's idiomatic groovy to use the `leftShift` method for append actions on strings, buffers, streams, arrays, etc and thats what you're seeing here.

For example:

- The overloaded `leftShift` methods on [`OutputStream`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/OutputStream.html) which are used to append bytes, an `InputStream`, or an `Object` to the stream.
- [`List`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#leftShift(java.lang.Object)), which also uses it as an append

You are looking at a grails tag lib, so out represents the page that's being rendered.  The results of this taglib will be added to the output buffer that will be rendered to the client.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming that *out* is *System.out* the << operator writes to *out* in this case.
The idiom to overload << for output (writing to a stream) and >> for input (reading from a stream) comes from C++. When the stdio libraries (istream ostream etc.) got defined, the idea was born to use left shift and right shift for output and input.